# web service with com

Tags: com

i am using in my web service (c#) a com object (*.dll Written in Delphi),on my localhost
(win xp 32bit iis 5.1) its working fine,allso its working fine on a client server (win 2003 32 bit),  recently thay moved to win server 2008 64 bit(iis 7.0) ,the web service working fine but now i get the following error:

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F9CFBBAD-F699-4957-9E6F-79083B7B57E6} failed due to the following error: 80040154.: at Service.logStatus(String firm, String sUser, String sPassword):App_Code "

i tryed the following:
1.regsvr32 (administrator)
2.put the dll in \WINDOWS\system32 and allso in \Windows\SysWOW64
3.looking in component services--->dcom comfig  (couldnt find the dll by name or CLSID)
4.set my web service to build in x86

i am Struggling with this Problem for 3 days please HELP!!!!!!!

Thanks Rotem

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling 32-bit mode in IIS:

[image]

Comment: Thanks
ok now i get the error:HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error