# Can't call COM Component from Web Service with IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis-7, com

I have a third party COM component which is called form a web servcice. While this works on my development machine I get this exception on the production server:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 
>   {6B7271AE-39C7-4C9E-B75F-6EDFCDBD623D} failed due to the following error:
>   80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Server: Win 2008 R2 Enterprise, 64 Bit

IIS: Version 7.5.7600.16385

**What I checked**

The registry entry

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{6B7271AE-39C7-4C9E-B75F-6EDFCDBD623D}
```

exists on the production server and points to the correct DLL (C:\Program Files (x86)...\xyz.DLL

(There are no other CLSID entries with this GUID in the registry)

Third Party's test program works correct on the production server

*(So the COM DLL is working ok)*

**What I tried**

A (C#/.Net) Console applicatipon can call the COM component correctly on the production server.

*(So .Net interop and com registration are ok)*

The web-service can call the COM component if run on my development machine.

*(So the program logic is ok)*

*Ich bin mit meinem Latein am Ende*

(german for: I be on my wit's end)

Comment: Can you confirm that your Application Pool is 32bit? Check `Enable 32-Bit Applications` in Advanced Settings of the AppPool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here: [web service with com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913620/web-service-with-com)
and from Peter Hahndorf the answer is quite simple:

The IIS Application Pool Setting `Enable 32 Bit Applications` must be true.

(IIS->Application Pools->Set Application Pool Defaults)

Then the web service can access the COM component.